HP ProBook 6570b: Boot device not found after installing Ubuntu
System Information
Laptop model: HP ProBook 6570b
Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 24.04.01
Issue: Boot device not found after installation
Issue Description
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS on my HP ProBook 6570b. The installation seemed to complete without any issues, but after rebooting, I get the following error:
"Boot device not found. Please install an operating system."
I am unable to boot into Ubuntu, and it seems like the system is not detecting the hard drive with the OS installed.
Request for Help*
How can I fix the "Boot device not found" issue and successfully boot into Ubuntu?
enter image description here
enter image description here

From the install media can you first run 'sudo gparted '. This will search and mount all your partitions including the install media & your HP device. Top right on menu bar is a drop down menu to select each disk. Identify you HP disk and note its path & name. You should see a partitioned disk with at least a Ubuntu partition (populated with data) & a UEFI partition used for booting. (You might get a picture.) Exit gparted.  From a terminal run the command  'sudo gdisk -l /dev/{your partition name}' and append the results to your question.

I tried as you told me, but it's still not working for me.
